# Platform driver's probe function isn't called

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, embedded, device-tree

I am developing a simple platform driver for beaglebone (but currently running on my virtual machine running Ubuntu) that uses device tree, but it doesn't seem like the probe function is being called.

From my understanding, in order for the probe to be called, you need to have matching `compatible` values (in the driver and device tree file), and have the platform driver registered. What am I possibly missing?

```c
struct of_device_id dt_match[] =
{
  {.compatible = "A1x"},
  {.compatible = "B2x"}
};

struct platform_driver platform_driver_struct =
{
  .probe = platform_driver_probe,
  .remove = platform_driver_remove,
  .id_table = pcdevs_ids,
  .driver = {
    .name = "pseudo-char-device",
    .of_match_table = dt_match
  }
};

static int __init platform_driver_init(void)
{
  platform_driver_register(&platform_driver_struct);
  return 0;
}
```

```
// dtsi file
/ {
    pcd-dev1 {
        compatible = "A1x";
        org,size=<512>;
        org,perm=<0x15>;
    };
    pcd-dev2 {
        compatible = "B2x";
        org,size=<256>;
        org,perm=<0x11>;
    };
};
```

And then I include the above DTSI file inside `am335x-boneblack.dts`. Then the binary is created using
`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- am33x-boneblack.dtb`

Aren't all the device tree files under `arch/arm/boot/dts` directory used by the kernel, and the respective probe function is called based on whether the `compatible` string matches?